# Shared Arrays not working

Tags: arrays, memory, singleton, memory-leaks, shared

I have a sqlite database application where I want to share an array across the application. Following is what I have done 
 - I have defined a singleton class with three arrays defined.
 - I am populating data in the arrays in a common class which I am using across different views

I have two problems

- if I alloc the arrays in singleton class the arrays are not holding values
- if I alloc the arrays in the common class - the application works but during Analyze it gives memory leak warning

I have searched the forum but could not get any answer or resolution to the same - appreciate any help

Comment: I would be helpful, if you mentioned the language you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer - As the Singleton class is instantiated once the arrays were not getting re-intialized to hold values of other view controller. I fixed it by having separate arrays for different view controllers